# RPI open a terminal on boot and auto-run a looping python script

Tags: python, bash, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

When my RPI3 is booted, I would like it to automatically have the terminal open with my python script already running. Note that it loops endlessly. I want to open the terminal so I check the logs my script produces.

I have searched ways that auto-runs python scripts on boots. I have tried putting `python /home/pi/Desktop/pythonfile.py` $ on /etc/rc.local but it just runs in the background and doesn't open a terminal.

What I also tried to do was use lxterminal. In /etc/rc.local, I put `sudo /home/pi/Desktop/bashfile.sh &`. Then the contents of bashfile.sh were:

```
#!bin/bash/

lxterminal --command="/bin/bash -c '/home/pi/Desktop/pythonfile.py; /bin/bash'"
```

When I try to manually run the bashfile.sh, the lxterminal opens and run the python script. However, when I rebooted, it doesn't open a terminal.

Any suggestions to this? Thanks.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/18223/66692

Comment: The fact it's a RPi is not as relevant as what distribution you're running on it. The "normal" answer would be to modify your `/etc/inittab` accordingly, but with some distros you may need to hack around systemd to do that.